Guide for use kotlin standard library
enter image description here
I am confused to use the Kotlin standard libraries that are available in the Kotlin documentation section and I don't know where to search to start my project, please guide me.
I don't need to use multi-platform Kotlin and I just want to write my app with Android Studio and I'm confused to use the library

If you're only targeting Android, then ignore any class/method/property descriptions that apply only to JS or Native. The only ones you are interested in are Common and JVM. Also, you might find the "Getting Started" page in the Kotlin documentation useful.

From android studio 2023.3, kotlin is included and not needed to use separately.


How does this answer OP's question exactly?

Hamed B mentioned that he/she just want to develop app in android studio. In this case android studio provide the kotlin setup and separate library setup is not required, this is what I tried to convey.
